# How to divide each value in column by the maximum value of a subset of that column

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, max

I am trying to divide each row in a column by the maximum of a sub-list in the column where the sub-list if the column filtered by a category variable

> Is there a single line vector equation that creates col3? I have been trying to use groupby with transform(lambda x: x...) but can't seem to get the effect of maxif where it only takes the max of col2 where col1 = the rows with the same category as the row in col2 being divided.

Sample input code:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'col1':['A', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
        'col2':[1, 2, 3, 4]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df
```

Desired output:

| `col1` | `col2` | `col3` | `explanation` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `A` | `1` | `0.5` | `e.g. 1/2` |
| `A` | `2` | `1` | `e.g. 2/2` |
| `B` | `3` | `0.75` | `e.g. 3/4` |
| `B` | `4` | `1` | `e.g. 4/4` |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure:

```py
>>> df['col2'] / df.groupby('col1')['col2'].transform(max)
0    0.50
1    1.00
2    0.75
3    1.00
```

You could then assign that result to a new column of your choice.